# Test type of value in Go

Tags: arrays, json, object, go, typeof

Im trying to validate a JSON object in Go. I'm trying to see if the 'tags' attribute is an array.( Later on I'll also want to know if another attribute is an object too).

I have reached to this. If I print `reflect.TypeOf(gjson.Get(api_spec, "tags").Value()` I get :

```
string   // When the field is a string
[]interface {} // When the field is an array
map[string]interface {} // When the field is an object
```

But when trying to test this on the below code :

```
if ( gjson.Get(api_spec, "tags").Exists() ) {
            if ( reflect.TypeOf(gjson.Get(api_spec, "tags").Value()) != "[]interface {}" ) {
             // some code here ...
            }
        }
```

I get the below error code :

```
invalid operation: reflect.TypeOf(gjson.Get(api_spec, "tags").Value()) != "[]interface {}" (mismatched types reflect.Type and string)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to determine if a value is a `[]interface{}`:

```
v := gjson.Get(api_spec, "tags").Value()
_, ok := v.([]interface{}) // ok is true if v is type []interface{}
```

Here's the code in the question modified to use a type assertion:

```
if gjson.Get(api_spec, "tags").Exists() {
    if _, ok := gjson.Get(api_spec, "tags").Value().([]interface{}); !ok {
        // some code here ...
    }
}
```

There's no need to use reflection.  If you do want to use reflection for some reason (and I don't see a reason in the question), then compare reflect.Type values:

```
// Get type using a dummy value. This can be done once by declaring
// the variable as a package-level variable.
var sliceOfInterface = reflect.TypeOf([]interface{}{})

ok = reflect.TypeOf(v) == sliceOfInterface  // ok is true if v is type []interface{}
```

[run the code on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Rz_cApI8Ska)

Comment: Thanks so much! Your second example is what I needed!

Answer (score 3):

When you print a type to console, it's converted to a string; however, [as you can see from the documentation for `TypeOf`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf), it does not return a `string`, it returns a `reflect.Type`. You can use `Kind()` to test programmatically what it is:

```
        if reflect.TypeOf(gjson.Get(api_spec, "tags").Value()).Kind() != reflect.Slice {
```

[Other `Kind`s](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Kind) you might be interested in are `reflect.String` and `reflect.Map`.

Answer (score 1):

`reflect.TypeOf` returns a `Type` object. See docs at https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#TypeOf

Your code should read:

```
if reflect.TypeOf(gjson.Get(api_spec, "tags").Value()).Name() != "[]interface {}" {
    // some code here ...
}
```